# How to write a Firebase Cloud Function that is only accessible through my app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My site references other websites. When a user follows the link to a site I want to increment a visit count for that website.

Websites (and others) are on a `/resources` endpoint on my database. It is readable publicly but not writable.

This means that a user that follows a link might not be authenticated.

So I need to write a Cloud Function that will increment the `visits` property of whatever website was visited.

But since users can be unauthenticated when doing that, I'd like to secure it by ensuring the request is coming from my own app.

Since my app has some special config for Firebase, I was hoping I could use that to send something that would allow me to check that this is indeed my app sending the request in order to avoid people spamming the endpoint and inflating visits.

Is that possible ? Or do I have to make it so only authenticated users can trigger the function ?

Comment: If you're using Callable Cloud Functions, this *is* now possible through Firebase App Check. See my answer here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191410/is-it-possible-to-only-accept-function-calls-from-my-app-in-firebase/67611797#67611797

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fully secure a function so that it can be accessed only from your app.  It will always be possible for someone to reverse engineer any "secret" that you pass from an unauthenticated user to your function.  You can certainly try to make it difficult for someone to discover that secret, but a determined hacker will be able to find it.