# Is it possible to only accept function calls from my app in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a game in Unity where the user can contribute with levels using a Level Creator system.

My application is setup in a way that I just need to call the Cloud Function with the level info, and it handles duplicate entries and saves it to Firestore. All of this works perfectly.

My question, basically, is: can I have my functions **only** accept calls from my game? (without having my users registered?).

Naturally, I am using `functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {})`. In [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) for Firebase, I noticed they use `context.auth` to check whether the user is authenticated or not. However, I am logging this value to the console and it appears to be `undefined`.

I am also confused with this line, from the same link:

> With callables, Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.

Maybe `context.auth` is not defined because my game isn't yet in Google Play / Apple Store? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict invocations of a callable function to just one app, and it doesn't matter if the app is published to any stores.  Once you deploy a function, it's accessible to anyone with an internet connection.

The best you can do is require your users to be authenticated with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) in your app, then check `context.auth` in the function to determine if the it should do what the user wants.  `context.auth` will be undefined in the case of no authentication.  If your code determines that the function should not go any further, you can return early.  But the function is still invoked.

Comment: ok, I don't want to require my users to be signed in: do you recommend then having them signed anonymously?

Comment: @SantiagoDegetau yes this would be an option. Simply somewhere encode a fix user and PW. **But** be aware that this can still be hacked ;) Either there is a blanc password lying around or you encrypt it .. but someone decompiling your app can still find out how you encrypt en reverse engineere it in order to call the methods manually... But at least it is harder then allowing that by default ;)

Comment: Yes, anonymous sign-in can be used this way, but it doesn't ensure that the user is actually using your app.

Comment: So far, is there any way to ensure that a non authenticated user is calling the function from my app?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to the new feature called [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), it is now actually possible to limit calls to Callable Cloud Functions to only those coming from iOS, Android and Web apps that are registered in your Firebase project.

You'll typically want to combine this with the user authentication based security that Doug describes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60191619), so that you have another shield against abusive users that *do* use your app.