# Firebase Callable Functions: Permission settings to restrict calling

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written some callable functions in both nodejs and python, and both are working fine when invoked from client side code. However, the current permission for `Cloud Functions Invoker` for these callable functions are set at `allUsers`. Removing `allUsers` will cause the function to throw `UNAUTHENTICATED`.

I want these callable functions to be invocable only from my firebase app, but I understand from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60191619/6792327) that such restriction isn't possible. So what is the best practice in restricting/limiting callable functions to be called only from my authenticated users to maintain security?

I have already done the necessary auth checks (I hope these suffice) to ensure that they are authenticated users on my app, ie:

```
//For python
authorization = request.headers.get('Authorization')
id_token = None

if authorization and authorization.startswith('Bearer '):
    id_token = authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
else:
    json_abort(401, message="No authorization found")

try:
    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
except Exception as e: 
    json_abort(403, message="Invalid authorization")

//For nodejs
module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let auth = context.auth

    if (!auth) throw new functions.https.HttpsError("permission-denied", "Caller is not authenticated.")
    //...
})
```

Is that all that I can do? Are there any other things at the resource permission level that I can implement instead of leaving `Cloud Functions Invoker` at `allUsers`?

Comment: This **is** now actually possible with Firebase App Check. See the new answer I added to the question you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611797

Answer (score 2):

> So what is the best practice in restricting/limiting callable functions to be called only from my authenticated users to maintain security?

You can't stop any client from invoking the function (the HTTP endpoints are always going to be public when you allow "allUsers"), so you have to check inside the function if auth credentials were provided by the client.  The code you're showing that checks `context.auth` should work just fine.