# Firebase Callable Function, restrict invoke to APP

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a react native application, I use firebase to authenticate the user with google account.

I want to disable public access to firebase http callable functions and make them accessible ONLY if invoked from my App.

At the moment if you get the auth token from the app you can easily invoke any http callable with Postman or similar program.

What are my options? The only way I can think is to pass an extra argument to the function, maybe encrypt it inside the app and decrypt it inside the function, is there some better way?

Comment: Partially, even if there is no built-in support there has to be some way to secure/close it to public access. It's still a node/express like function, I'm just looking for a better suggestion than my sending an encrypted text to the function and decrypt it to verify that it came from my app.

Comment: Even in that case, anyone who has your app can get the encrypted text to send, much like they can get the app key (or the key to sign/encrypt whatever you need them to sign).  The best bet would be to verify that the user is an authorized user of the app, but that only prohibits anonymous access.  [Also see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191410/is-it-possible-to-only-accept-function-calls-from-my-app-in-firebase)

Comment: I'm already using context.auth to make sure it only allows authenticated users, but I'm sure someone smarter than me has a solution for this.

Comment: You can't restrict network access to a function from only a certain app.  Cloud services need to be public in order to work correctly.  You will have to check auth in order to verify that the user is allowed to do what the function is going to do for them.